# How to get the saved drop down value from controller to view

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to hit the controller to fetch the saved value and bind it to search parameter using jquery i tried the below  code but i could not hit the controller using ajax call

Comment: Typically the controller would need to be *told* what the selected value is, by the form being submitted; jQuery scripts could get access to it using something like `$('#dropDownID').val()`

Comment: I think I see.  Do you intend to dynamically (via AJAX) get the corresponding id from the database after the user has selected the "patientID"?

Comment: no on clicking the tab2 i need to bind patientid and dropdown id patient id i will be getting through login but to get the drop down saved i have ajax function which is hitting my controller but before that hit it is hitting this tab2

Comment: added my ajax code also by explaining my pblm

Comment: is "click on tab2" causing a new request/response and/or form submission, or is it just toggling visibility on a DOM element?  (I'm trying to get more information behind your statement: "i am unable to use this value when i click tab2")

Comment: I will explain in detail the drop down value is getting binded correctly but the grid that is getting binded for that value is not correct suppose i have 5 drop down values and i have saved 3 drop down value to be my default value so next time when i login my output should be 3rd drop down and its corresponding grid but what is happening means 3 drop down value is only my default but the grid is not corresponding to third drop down it is always taking the drop down which is at zero index

Comment: since using ajax call i am unable to bind that value which is in db.I need to modify this line searchCriteria.CareTeamId = $("#ddlCareTeam :selected").val(); in such a way that it will hit the controller and get that value from controller

Comment: It looks like your server-side framework is C#/MVC.  Is that correct?  If so, I'd expect your controller method to be marked with `[HttpGet]` and return a JsonResult

Comment: i am using httpget only if that is not correct then i could not bind the drop value correctly value is binding correctly only but the grid data for that value is not correct because of this line searchCriteria.CareTeamId = $("#ddlCareTeam :selected").val(); instead of this line i should use the code to fetch value from controller

Comment: Pretty sure you need to change that controller method to return a JsonResult so the framework will route it as an AJAX call.  You just need to change the return type, and then change your `return list;` line to `return Json(list);`

Comment: can you show me the sample code my requirement is i need to have drop down values where any one of the item can be set to default after setting it to default i need to save that value in db and when user logins i need to bind that value to drop down if you can help me i will post my complete code which i am using now

Comment: i got the issue my ajax call is not hitting for the first time it is hitting second time can you let me know how to make it hit every time

Comment: OK, that sound like a timing problem -- something on your page is loading dynamically, so you should explicitly make the ajax call after it's done loading.  If you're populating some of those elements in a document ready handler (`$()` or `$.ready()`) just make sure the ajax call is being made after the DOM is ready for it -- note that just calling it on the "next line" won't do it, since ajax calls don't block -- you'd need it to be called in a callback handler

Comment: ya resolved my issue